# IAR Teminal IO not logging printf output

Tags: arm, embedded, iar

I am building an embedded application project using the **IAR Embedded Workbench Arm 8.30.1**. I used `printf` statement to log output to the `Terminal IO`. However, i can't  see the output logged to the `Terminal IO window and the log file. But the`Auto Window` displays the values of the variable correctly. I am using ST-Link debugger.

[No output in Terminal IO after the printf statement is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBvcG.png)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Have you enabled semihosting?

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the code

Comment: What is semihosting? Could you please explain me, I am new to this IDE

Comment: To my understanding, enabling semihosting links your binary with special version of standard library that allows streaming of standard input, output and error streams through your debugger. See your compiler and IDE manuals for details.

Comment: If you based your project on an example from ST it may include implementations of printf and friends that send output to a random serial port somewhere.

Comment: Do you have all necessary connections between the ST-Link and your target?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Project, opention general options, library config = enable semi-hosting. Just to the right, pick the "stout/sterr" method - "via hosting", or via "SWO" if you have a debugger pod attached.
2. Download to start the debug session. Chose View->Terminal I/O,, and you printfs should come out there.

Bug IAR if it can't work - they can help also.

Comment: That option does not seem to exist: https://imgur.com/a/DLmw4yn (no matter what option I choose under `library`)
Am I missing something?